# Get max value of 3 items from list

Tags: c#

I have a problem.
I created a list that looks like this:

```
public class SelectedTriangleRegistryObject
{
    public float x1 { get; set; }
    public float y1 { get; set; }
    public float x2 { get; set; }
    public float y2 { get; set; }
    public float x3 { get; set; }
    public float y3 { get; set; }
    public int TriangleNum { get; set; }
    public int SequenceNum { get; set; }
}
```

Now I want to select the maximum value of the x coordinates. So the highest number, but that could be either x1, x2 or x3. Just the highest value of the 3. How can I do that?

I know this line:

```
float XMaxShapeValue = triangles.Max(x => x.x3);
```

But know I want something like this:

`float XMaxShapeValue = triangles.Max(x => x.x1, x.x2, x.x3);`

How can I do that?

**EXAMPLE:**

x1 has the values [2,4,5]
x2 has the values [2,5,3]
x3 has the values [4,6,1]

Then I want to get number 6. But you don't know which x has the highest number!

Comment: What's the 3 together? The sum of them? `Max(x => x.x1 + x.x2 + x.x3)`?

Comment: Write a static method `public static T Max<T>(params T[] args) => args.Max();`. Or add a property `public double MaxX => new[] { x1, x2, x3 }.Max();`

Comment: No, the highest number of x1, x2 or x3. It depends on which one is higher....

Comment: `Math.Max(a, Math.Max(b,c))` ?

Comment: @A.Vreeswijk As we know from math, maximum operation is associative, that is `max(a, b, c)` is equal to `max(a, max(b, c))`. Just use `Math.Max` twice.

Comment: I have added an example to the question!

Comment: So are x1, x2, etc. supposed to be arrays?

Comment: @A.Vreeswijk Do you want to return the float value or the `SelectedTriangleRegistryObject` object that has that max value? In case you want the object, what do you do in case of a tie?

Comment: No but the list has multiple indexes!

Comment: The highest number, it doesn't matter which x has it. Just the highest number

Comment: @MarcGravell Already gave you the answer... And that example is terrible, it represents three lists not one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apply the suggestions from the comments to use two `Math.Max` statements to your LINQ query:

```
float XMaxShapeValue = triangles.Max(t => Math.Max(t.x1, Math.Max(t.x2, t.x3)));
```

This will return the `float` value of the max X no matter if it is `x1`, `x2`, or `x3`. This will not return the triangle object that actually has the max X value.

Answer (score 0):

To find the maximum in float arrays:

```
float[] x1 = {1, 2, 3};
float[] x2 = {2, 3, 4};
float[] x3 = {3, 4, 5};

float max(float[]...floatArrays) {
    max = Float.MIN;
    foreach (float[] floats in floatArrays) {
        foreach (f in floats) {
            max = Math.Max(float, max);
        }
    }
    return max;
}
```

I don't really understand the question but going by your example, this is what you want.

Comment: `float` is a keyword and you can't use it as a variable name

Comment: whoops, my bad!